# MySQL: Operar con alias

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

¿No es posible incluir los alias que se definen en una consulta en operaciones posteriores?

Es decir, necesito hacer esto:

```
CASE WHEN tgd.generic_id = 11008 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS qt_sent_madison,
1 - (CASE WHEN tgd.generic_id = 11008 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qt_not_sent_madison,
```

Cuando sería mucho más cómodo hacer esto:

```
CASE WHEN tgd.generic_id = 11008 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS qt_sent_madison,
1 - qt_sent_madison AS qt_not_sent_madison,
```

Pero al intentarlo me devuelve un error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'qt_sent_madison' in 'field list'
```

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Para eso están las subconsultas, las vistas, si fuera escalar incluso las variables y, ya si necesitas algo más complicado, los procedimientos almacenados y funciones, a los que puedes llamar desde eventos y disparadores. Ya sabes cómo se funciona aquí: sube un dataset de pruebas en SQL, intenta cualquiera de las posibilidades que te he comentado con un ejemplo concreto y te echamos una mano para echarlo a andar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ¡Ánimo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un gusto.

Te comento lo que sucede con el alias. Los alias solo sirven para dar un sobrenombre a la subconsulta, campo, tabla, etcétera de tu consulta. El alias **NO** se define como un campo, es por ello que te marca ese error. Tendrías que poner la misma sentencia donde va el alias.

Si quieres ocuparlo de la manera que lo solicitas sería mejor que utilizarás las variables que brinda la base de datos.

p.e.

```
SET @qt_sent_madison = (SELECT CASE WHEN tgd.generic_id = 11008 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
SELECT 1 - @qt_sent_madison AS qt_not_sent_madison;
```

Comment: El problema es que esa consulta luego la envío a una aplicación BI, con lo cual creo que sería un poco engorroso definir variables; y ya subconsultas o vistas, imposible.